# Reusing variables declared on Try-Catch

Tags: c++, try-catch

I am using a try-catch block like this one:

```
try {

    Texture heightmapTexture = Texture("Snow0101_7_M.jpg");

} catch (TextureLoadException exc) {
    std::cout << exc.what() << std::endl;
}
```

The thing is that I need to reuse the variable heightmapTexture further in my program.
So I realized I can't do that because of the scope. Should I put the rest of the program inside the scope? For me that doesn't make any sense.

I also can't declare the variable outside of the scope because I have to initialize it. It has a constructor that only receives a string as input.

What would be the best solution?

I realize that I could use a pointer, but I am trying to avoid that (I am not really good at preventing memory leaks).

EDIT: Sorry, I was declaring the variable as a class Heightmap, which is wrong!, it is a texture object. But the problem is the same.

Comment: Use a boost::shared_ptr instead of raw pointers, will avoid leaks and will solve the problem.

Comment: An object that can be initialized but not assigned? Can you change that class?

Comment: what do you mean @Silicomancer? I guess it will have to be a pointer then.

Comment: Can you change the source code of class Heightmap?

Comment: yes, It is a class from a tutorial.

Comment: You could add a default constructor and an assignment operator to Heightmap it so you can first define an empty object (before try) and then assign the texture in the try block. BTW *why* do you want to reuse the object?

Comment: Ahm, the object has to methods of Binding and Unbinding the texture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you'd normally want all your logic inside one try/catch context. Presumably if the loading of a texture fails, everything after it will fail also?

in which case you might be able to express the logic more neatly as:

```
try {
    Heightmap heightmapTexture = Texture("Snow0101_7_M.jpg");

    // do your work here

    // if anything fails fatally, throw

    // do you need to store the height map in an object?
    my_object.give_heightmap(std::move(heightmapTexture));
} 
// report failures here
catch (TextureLoadException& exc) { // note: by reference
    std::cout << exc.what() << std::endl;
}
catch (OtherReason& e) {
    // report the reason
}
catch(exception& e) {
  // other failures
}
```

A good way to think about exception handling is that an exception object is the explanation you are being given for a process or sequence failing, rather than each exception being an error code for one operation.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your variable outside of the try-catch block like so.

```
Heightmap *heightmapTexture = null;

try {

    heightmapTexture = new Texture("Snow0101_7_M.jpg");

} catch (TextureLoadException exc) {
    std::cout << exc.what() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I can't do that in c++

Comment: no! Firstly, this requires Heightmap to have a default constructor. Secondly it defeats the purpose of exception handling.

Comment: raw pointers are evil. do not use

Comment: @RichardHodges no default constructor is required here